# How to replace rows in a table with 'NaNs', leaving the matrix dimension unchanged? (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, replace, nan

Let's assume the following:

```
A=rand(10,5);
```

How can I replace the first 3 rows of this table with NaN's, without the matrix losing its original dimension 10x5? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just index into the first three rows but ensure you select all of the columns and replace the entries with `nan`:

```
A(1:3,:) = nan;
```

I have a minor comment.  The variable `A` is **not** a `table`, but it is a matrix.  Please ensure you use the right terminology from now on, as someone may confuse what you're saying with the actual [`table`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) construct.